# wordpress insert post doesnt work on edge

Tags: php, wordpress

I create a code to save data from Form to custom_post_type.
Everything ok on Firefox but when I test it on edge, the post still save, but I can't edit the post on admin, or view the post(object not found) (see the image)

[image]

I really don't know where is the problem, please help.

this is my code, i copy it from my function.php:

```
    function wpshout_frontend_post() {
     wpshout_save_post_if_submitted();
    ?>
    <div>
        <div>
            RESERVATION
        </div>      
            <form id="new_post" class = 'datcho' name="new_post" method="post">
            <input type = 'text' name = 'ten' required>
            <input type = 'tel' name = 'sdt' required>
            <input type = 'number' name = 'num' min='1' max = '10' required>
            <input type = 'date' name = 'ngay' required>
            <input type = 'time' name = 'time' value = '13:00' min='9:00' max='21:00' required>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'wps-frontend-post' ); ?>


            <input type="submit" value="Reservation" id="submit" name="submit"/>

            </div>
            </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function wpshout_save_post_if_submitted() {
    // Stop running function if form wasn't submitted
    if ( !isset($_POST['ten']) ) {
        return; 
    }
    // Check that the nonce was set and valid
    if( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wpnonce'], 'wps-frontend-post') ) {
        echo 'Did not save because your form seemed to be invalid. Sorry';
        return;
    }

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $title = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['ten']);
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $title,
        'post_status'   => 'Pending',   
        'post_type'     => 'datcho' 
    );

   $eror = wp_insert_post($post,true);
    if($eror){
        $sdt = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['sdt']);
        $ngay = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['ngay']);
        $time = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['time']);
        $num = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['num']);
        add_post_meta($eror, 'sdt', $sdt);
        add_post_meta($eror, 'ngay', $ngay);
        add_post_meta($eror, 'time', $time);
        add_post_meta($eror, 'num', $num);
        echo 'Saved your post successfully! :)';
    }else {
        echo "something wrong";
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please remove the `</div>` before `</form>` and then try again? Also change the 'post_status' to `draft` or `publish`

Comment: @SaqibAmin thanks for your help. if I change the post_status to publish then I can view the post(client view) but still can't select that post to delete or edit. Every thing work fine on Firefox, you can see in the picture there is some post  normal.

Comment: I think I have some problem with my custom_post_type. if i change 'post_type' to 'post', it work ok. If you have any clue, please tell me. I'm is new to WordPress :(

Comment: Can you confirm if you are logged into Wordpress in Firefox and not in Edge?

Comment: yes, i login my admin account in Firefox and not in Edge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete solution.
The issue mainly is you are not logged into the WP in Edge so when creating the post using `wp_insert_post` wordpress has no idea with which account should it attach that post.

```
    function wpshout_frontend_post() {
     wpshout_save_post_if_submitted();
    ?>
    <div>
        <div>
            RESERVATION
        </div>      
            <form id="new_post" class = 'datcho' name="new_post" method="post">
            <input type = 'text' name = 'ten' required>
            <input type = 'tel' name = 'sdt' required>
            <input type = 'number' name = 'num' min='1' max = '10' required>
            <input type = 'date' name = 'ngay' required>
            <input type = 'time' name = 'time' value = '13:00' min='9:00' max='21:00' required>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'wps-frontend-post' ); ?>


            <input type="submit" value="Reservation" id="submit" name="submit"/>

            </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function wpshout_save_post_if_submitted() {
    // Stop running function if form wasn't submitted
    if ( !isset($_POST['ten']) ) {
        return; 
    }
    // Check that the nonce was set and valid
    if( !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['_wpnonce'], 'wps-frontend-post') ) {
        echo 'Did not save because your form seemed to be invalid. Sorry';
        return;
    }

    // Do some minor form validation to make sure there is content

    // Add the content of the form to $post as an array
    $title = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['ten']);
    $author_id = 1; // You can change it with your User ID
    $post = array(
        'post_title'    => $title,
        'post_content'  => $title,
        'post_status'   => 'draft',   
        'post_type'     => 'datcho'
        'post_author'     => $author_id 
    );

   $eror = wp_insert_post($post,true);
    if($eror){
        $sdt = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['sdt']);
        $ngay = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['ngay']);
        $time = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['time']);
        $num = wp_strip_all_tags($_POST['num']);
        add_post_meta($eror, 'sdt', $sdt);
        add_post_meta($eror, 'ngay', $ngay);
        add_post_meta($eror, 'time', $time);
        add_post_meta($eror, 'num', $num);
        echo 'Saved your post successfully! :)';
    }else {
        echo "something wrong";
    }
}
```